# How do I handle a web page that doesn't work on ASP.NET Core?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, svg, razor, .net-6.0

Sorry for  I'm a newbie.I'm trying to render the data in the database in real time, updating the variables via Timer. Then I import the variables into SVG rendering, but when I add Timer to the web page, the web page will not work, and there will be no errors, how can I debug my code?

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<MPU_02.Models.Mpu>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}    
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg width="600" height="600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg">
            <g>
             <title>Layer 1</title>
             <rect stroke-width="5" rx="20" id="svg_1" height="590" width="590" y="5" x="5" stroke="#000" fill="#999999"/>
             <ellipse ry="150" rx="150" id="svg_2" cy="256" cx="256" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000" fill="#7fff00"/>
             <rect rx="10" id="svg_3" height="40" width="300" y="480" x="111" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000" fill="#7fff00"/>
             <rect rx="10" id="svg_4" height="300" width="40" y="111" x="480" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000" fill="#7fff00"/>
             <line opacity="0.5" id="svg_8" y2="211" x2="520" y1="211" x1="480" stroke-width="3" stroke="#000" fill="none"/>
             <line opacity="0.5" id="svg_9" y2="311" x2="520" y1="311" x1="480" stroke-width="3" stroke="#000" fill="none"/>
             <line opacity="0.5" id="svg_10" y2="520" x2="211" y1="480" x1="211" stroke-width="3" stroke="#000" fill="none"/>
             <line opacity="0.5" id="svg_11" y2="520" x2="311" y1="480" x1="311" stroke-width="3" stroke="#000" fill="none"/>
             <line opacity="0.5" id="svg_12" y2="256" x2="406" y1="256" x1="106" stroke-width="3" stroke="#000" fill="none"/>
             <line opacity="0.5" id="svg_13" y2="406" x2="256" y1="106" x1="256" stroke-width="3" stroke="#000" fill="none"/>
             <ellipse opacity="0.8" ry="30" rx="30" id="c" cy="256" cx="256" stroke="#BBBBBB" fill="#00ff00"/>
             <ellipse opacity="0.8" ry="20" rx="30" id="h" cy="500" cx="256" stroke="#999999" fill="#7fff00"/>
             <ellipse opacity="0.8" ry="30" rx="20" id="v" cy="256" cx="500" stroke="#999999" fill="#7fff00"/>
            </g>
           </svg>
    </body>
    </html>
    
    @{
        var timer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        double H=0.0;
        double V=0.0;
        while (await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync())
        {
            H = Model.LastOrDefault().Ax;
            V = Model.LastOrDefault().Ay;
           
        }
    
        
    }
    <script>
        
        function fakeData(){
            return {h:@H , v:@V*-1}
        }
        function changePos(){
            const c = document.getElementById("c")
            const h = document.getElementById("h")
            const v = document.getElementById("v")
            console.log(c, h, v)
            const data = fakeData()
            var transformAttrX = 'translate(' + data.h * 150 + ',0)';
            var transformAttrY = 'translate(0,' + data.v * 150 + ')';
            var transformAttrXY = 'translate('+ data.h * 150 +"," + data.v * 150 + ')';
            c.setAttribute('transform', transformAttrXY);
            h.setAttribute('transform', transformAttrX);
            v.setAttribute('transform', transformAttrY);
        }
        setInterval(fakeData,2000)
        setInterval(changePos,3000)
    
    </script>
```

**Mpu.cs**

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IdGenerators;

namespace MPU_02.Models
{
    
    
    public class Mpu
    {

        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        
        public string? Id { get; set; }
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Double, AllowTruncation = true)]
        public double Yaw { get; set; }
        public double Pitch { get; set; }
        public double Roll { get; set; }
        public double Ax { get; set; }

        public double Ay { get; set; }
        public double Az { get; set; }
        public double Gx { get; set; }
        public double Gy { get; set; }
        public double Gz { get; set; }
        public double Mx { get; set; }

        public double My { get; set; }
        public double Mz { get; set; }
        public double Temp { get; set; }

        


    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to debug? your `Javascript` or `C#` code? Could you please share your `MPU_02.Models.Mpu` model and details of your implementation so that it can be reproducible.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron OK, I have update.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron   When I wasn't using Timer, it worked fine.

Comment: H = Model.LastOrDefault().Ax;
V = Model.LastOrDefault().Ay;

Comment: Yes your this line creating the problem `wait timer.WaitForNextTickAsync()` because it get called like infinitive loop that while it will not stops and next execution will not be started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***`"The web page will not work, and there will be no errors"`***

> This will not work because of your this line of code:  `while (await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync())` its will be working like a infinite
> loop and keep continue looping and eventually your `HTML` and
> `Javascipt` will not be executed as expected.

***`"how can I debug my code?"`***

> For `C#`  code you can debug like the way we debug normally `C#` code
> as you can see the picture below:

[image]

***`Note:`***

If you get rid of your code `while (await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync())` then it will work like below:

[image]

> Another problem I got from your `Javascript` code that is, you are
> calling `fakeData()` and `changePos()` function on `setInterval` but
> you are passting the `function` like this
> `setInterval(fakeData,2000)` I think it whould like  `setInterval(fakeData(),2000)` instead.

Hope it would help you to debug your code accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, I have a doubt, if I am missing this while(), how do I refresh my value? Can it only be done through websocket?

Comment: Currently your value updating in `infinite manner`, because time will be updated continuously so your program will never go out of this execution and it will blocked forever. So whatever you do make sure there is no blocking and for `websocket` you could use it only the scenario where you would require to update too many user or listener together if there is a single update from backend which need to inform all. If you have any further concern you could post different post providing some reproducible sample, would be glad to assist you there.